# PDI Step MongoDB Input - $match using value gotten from a MySQL query in a previous step

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

My transformation starts with a Table input step with a query that retrieves a value from a table column (named ID_EXECUCAO).
I want to search my MongoDB Collection filtering by this value, using the function $match on my MongoDB input step query.

I know I can search by a parameter using "${PARAMETER}", but how do I search by a value passed from a previous step?

I tried this way and it doesn't work:

```
$match: {
    "IdExecucao": $ID_EXECUCAO
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail.  Please show the error, and please provide sample data you are attempting to query.

Comment: and please include the entire pipeline

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I sure that you can't do it by get data from previous step like 'Table Input Step'. No option 'Insert data from step' in MongoDB Input.
As you known, the only way is to use Variable (${VARIABLE_NAME}).